# Does JProfiler have an equivalent -javaagent alternative to the native agent

Tags: jprofiler, javaagents

I was planning to use JProfiler to...err...profile my current project. However, my target architecture is not one that is currently supported.

Does there exist -javaagent alternative to the native agent; a javaagent that the JProfiler GUI can connect to remotely and do its thing?

NDA's and the like preclude me from including anything more specific.

Comment: What is your target architecture?

Answer (score 0):

The JProfiler agent uses the profiling interface JVMTI which is a native interface. While it would be possible to record a small subset of the displayed data with a Java agent, it would require a duplicate implementation in Java code.

Java agents are less suitable for general profiling than native agents since they have to allocate all their resources on the heap.

If you're just interested in memory profiling, you can use tools like `jmap` (included in the JDK) to extract an HPROF snapshot that can be opened in JProfiler.